# Marker clipped/hidden in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm using icon markers to display rotatable historical maps atop an OL3 layer.

Unfortunately, when I zoom in, the marker will be suddenly hidden if the southern or eastern edge goes out of the view.

Is there any way keep it visible until the whole image is off-screen?

Comment: Hi Bill. I think your problem is about your Views "extent". If your icons position appears to be outside the extent it will be turned off. But It's hard to say when I don't have your code.

Comment: I think it occurs when the point it's attached to goes off screen,  something you'd want to have happen with a marker. The extent is probably ok. Thanks